# pushViewController is not pushing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, navigation, pushviewcontroller

I was using initWithNibName to push the cells to detail views but I want to use single storyboard rather than having numerous nib files. The below code is supposed to push the view to subcategoriesViewController when the cell is clicked. the cells are dynamic from json data.

Its not giving any errors. Do you think its an issue with navigation control? Just to test, I added a button on this view and it works; when I click it, it does push to next view.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [rows objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];


    subcategoriesViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"subcategoriesViewController"];
    controller.CATNAME = [dict objectForKey:@"C_NAME"];
    controller.CATNUMBER = [dict objectForKey:@"CAT_ID"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
//    [controller release];
}
```

Okay I think I have found the cause; but don't know how to fix it.

The tableview in this controller is actually a subview of a viewController. I duplicated these files and created a new view which is a TableViewController. This code, when used in the TableViewController does the job, but it doesn't do it when used in a controller where the tableview is a subview of a ViewController.

I want the table to be a subview because I want to put an image above the table. So, I think the problem here is this line:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

It does not reference the table in the view. Can anyone tell me how to modify this so it would reference the table within the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `didSelectRow...` is not being called then your view controller is probably not set as the delegate of your table view.

This is set up for you automatically when using a UITableViewController but you have to explicitly do it when using a standard view controller.

Comment: Yes. This makes sense. I thought of it but I used the following bit of code to do it. Isn't that good enough?
 
@interface categoriesViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>{
    
    
 UITableView *tableview;
}

Comment: That is right, but you also need to tell the table view who it's delegate is. You can connect this in your storyboard, drag the delegate outlet from the table view to the view controller.

Comment: I did that but it then started crashing without giving reasons. I guess I'll make a fresh start tomorrow. Thanks for your time.

Comment: A referencing outlet from the tableview to view controller solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

An answer to your problem is often that `self.navigationController` is in fact `nil` because there is no navigation controller for your view. You perhaps have to get a pointer to the navigation controller of your projet and push your view on it.

Comment: No it's not nil. I checked it with Nslog to be sure. I still think the problem is referencing.

Comment: is it the navigation controller you think it is ?

Comment: Turns out it was a referencing missing at the interface builder.