# Pushing viewController from a tableview that is inside a viewController not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am having an issue pushing my view controller from a tableview that was dropped into a viewController, and not a TableViewController.

I have found a thread on here with a solution here

[pushViewController is not pushing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552531/pushviewcontroller-is-not-pushing)

The problem is.. I have done his solution and my view still does not push.  I have connected my tableview via ctrl+drag to the view controller and set both the dataSource and delegate.  In the post i mentioned, they say the solution was to 'create a referencing outlet from the tableview to the view controller.'  But I don't exactly know what that means.  So help with that would be good as well.  I have followed [this tutorial](http://kurrytran.blogspot.com/2011/10/ios-5-storyboard-and.html) and am stuck on step 9 obviously.

The line of code not triggering is

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:facility animated:YES];
```

My code is as follows...

viewTable methods

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{   
 NSLog(@"list Size: %@",list);
    return [list count];
}

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
CustomerListData *customer = [self.list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = customer.facilityName;

// cell.textLabel.text = @"Detail";
return cell;
}

-(void)setValue:(NSMutableArray*)array
{ 
//NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
list = array;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

FacilityMissionListViewController *facility = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"facilityMissionList"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:facility animated:YES]; 
//UINavigationController* navController = self.navigationController;
}
```

the very last commented out line is there to check if navigationcontroller was null.  It is not.

From what I have gathered the issue here lies in the fact the table view is inside the view controller and its not a "tableviewcontroller."  This method apparently works if that is the case, but some other steps must be taken if not.. but I don't know them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your NavigationController is not set up correctly.  Could you post the code that sets it up?

Comment: My mistake.. the nav controller was never set up (its been a while since I worked on this project).  I have been using segues instead of the nav controller for all of my view transitions.  I switched to a segue setup and it worked just fine.  I guess now my question is.. will this effect anything with the table and passing of data etc?  Is there any difference between using segues or the nav controller?

Comment: From what I understand, you will still have to set up and pass data to the new ViewController (facility) like you did before.

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  As long as functionally its basically the same all is well.

Answer (score 0):

Put a :

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController);
```

in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method and you'll see if the method is being called and if the navigationController is nil. It might be one of this cases.

Otherwise make sure that the FacilityMissionListViewController is not nil either.

Comment: Ok, clicking the button does call the method, but self.navigationcontroller is in fact null.  Apparently the other way to check was inaccurate.  So what do I do from here?